# Pods not communicating with Gossip Router and hence not forming JGroups single cluster

Tags: kubernetes, jgroups

I have a stateful set as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: jgroups-leader-poc
  labels:
    app: jgroups-leader-poc
spec:
  serviceName: jgroups-leader-poc
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jgroups-leader-poc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jgroups-leader-poc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jgroups-leader-poc-container
          image: localhost:5001/jgroups-leader-ui:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: jgroups.gossip_routers
              value: "localhost[12001]"
            - name: jgroups.tcp.ip
              value: "site_local,match-interface:eth0"
            - name: jgroups.tcp.ntfnport
              value: "7800"
            - name: JGROUPS_EXTERNAL_ADDR
              value: "match-interface:eth0"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 7800
              name: k8sping-port
```

TcpGossip.xml as follows

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <TCP external_addr="${JGROUPS_EXTERNAL_ADDR:match-interface:eth0}"
         bind_addr="${jgroups.tcp.ip}" bind_port="${jgroups.tcp.ntfnport:0}"
         sock_conn_timeout="300"
         max_bundle_size="60000"
         enable_diagnostics="false"

         thread_naming_pattern="cl"
         thread_pool.enabled="true"
         thread_pool.min_threads="1"
         thread_pool.max_threads="25"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000" />

    <TCPGOSSIP initial_hosts="${jgroups.gossip_routers:localhost[12001]}" reconnect_interval="3000"/>
    <MERGE3 min_interval="10000" max_interval="30000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD_ALL timeout="60000" interval="15000" timeout_check_interval="5000"/>
    <FD_HOST check_timeout="5000" interval="15000" timeout="60000"/>
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="5000"/>
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false" use_mcast_xmit_req="false" xmit_interval="1000"/>
    <UNICAST3 xmit_table_max_compaction_time="3000" />
    <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="5000" view_bundling="true"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="30K"/>
    <pbcast.STATE buffer_size="1048576" max_pool="10"/>
    <pbcast.FLUSH timeout="0"/>
</config>
```

And I have started Gossip Router as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gossiprouter
  labels:
    run: gossiprouter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: gossiprouter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: gossiprouter
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: belaban/gossiprouter:latest
          name: gossiprouter
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8787
            - containerPort: 9000
            - containerPort: 12001
          env:
            - name: LogLevel
              value: "TRACE"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gossiprouter
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - port: 8787
      targetPort: 8787
      name: debug
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      name: netcat
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 12001
      targetPort: 12001
      name: gossiprouter
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: gossiprouter
```

when I do `kubectl get pods`

[image]

`kubectl get svc` shows

[image]

Source code for reference:

```
public class Chatter extends ReceiverAdapter {
    JChannel channel;
    @Value("${app.jgroups.config:jgroups-config.xml}")
    private String jGroupsConfig;

    @Value("${app.jgroups.cluster:chat-cluster}")
    private String clusterName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()  {
       try {
            channel = new JChannel(jGroupsConfig);
            channel.setReceiver(this);
            channel.connect(clusterName);
            checkLeaderStatus();
            channel.getState(null, 10000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("registering the channel in JMX failed: {}", ex);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        channel.close();
    }

    public void viewAccepted(View newView) {
        log.info("view: " + newView);
        checkLeaderStatus();
    }

    private void checkLeaderStatus() {
        Address address = channel.getView().getMembers().get(0);
        if (address.equals(channel.getAddress())) {
            log.info("Nodes are started, I'm the master!");
        }
        else
        {
            log.info("Nodes are started, I'm a slave!");
        }
    }

}
```

The issue here is none of the pods are getting connected to running gossip router although `localhost:12001` is given as `jgroups.gossip_routers` in the Statefulset. Hence all the pods are forming separate jgroups cluster instead of single cluster.

Gossip router service details as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay! Do you have a public image for `jgroups-leader-ui:1.0`?
I suspect that the members don't communicate with each other because they connect directly to each other, possibly some issue with `external_addr`.

Why are you using `TCP:TCPGOSSIP` instead of `TUNNEL:PING`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the image cannot be publicly shared as it is part of my company policy. Also, TCP: TCPGOSSIP is being used in legacy application which we are porting to Kubernetes environment hence changing the protocol is out the question as of now. Could you please brief about what should be the value to be given for external_addr?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I tried this out with a sample app/image (`chat.sh`) / `belaban/jgroups`.

Try the following steps:

- `kubectl apply -f gossiprouter.yaml` (your existing YAML)
- Find the address of eth of the GossipRouter pod (in my case below: `172.17.0.3`)
- `kubectl -f jgroups.yaml` (the Yaml is pasted below)
- `kubectl exec jgroups-0 probe.sh` should list 3 members:

```
/Users/bela$ kubectl exec jgroups-0 probe.sh
#1 (180 bytes):
local_addr=jgroups-1-42392
physical_addr=172.17.0.5:7800
view=[jgroups-0-13785|2] (3) [jgroups-0-13785, jgroups-1-42392, jgroups-2-14656]
cluster=chat
version=4.2.4.Final (Julier)

#2 (180 bytes):
local_addr=jgroups-0-13785
physical_addr=172.17.0.4:7800
view=[jgroups-0-13785|2] (3) [jgroups-0-13785, jgroups-1-42392, jgroups-2-14656]
cluster=chat
version=4.2.4.Final (Julier)

#3 (180 bytes):
local_addr=jgroups-2-14656
physical_addr=172.17.0.6:7800
view=[jgroups-0-13785|2] (3) [jgroups-0-13785, jgroups-1-42392, jgroups-2-14656]
cluster=chat
version=4.2.4.Final (Julier)

3 responses (3 matches, 0 non matches)
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: jgroups
  labels:
    run: jgroups
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: jgroups
  serviceName: "jgroups"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: jgroups
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: belaban/jgroups
        name: jgroups
        command: ["chat.sh"]
        args: ["-props gossip.xml"]
        env:
          - name: DNS_QUERY
            value: "jgroups.default.svc.cluster.local"
          - name: DNS_RECORD_TYPE
            value: A
          - name: TCPGOSSIP_INITIAL_HOSTS
            value: "172.17.0.3[12001]"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
#  annotations:
#    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
  name: jgroups
  labels:
    run: jgroups
spec:
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: ping
      port: 7800
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 7800
    - name: probe
      port: 7500
      protocol: UDP
      targetPort: 7500
    - name: debug
      port: 8787
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8787
    - name: stomp
      port: 9000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9000
  selector:
     run: jgroups
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
```

Comment: The change was that `TCPGOSSIP_INITIAL_HOSTS` had to point to the IP address of the GossipRouter (default was `localhost`). With the default networking, you don't need external address